# Could not execute menu item (internal error)[Exception] - When changing PHP version from 5.3.1 to 5.2.9

Tags: php, wampserver, system-error

I have installed two PHP versions in my WAMP server. When I am using 5.3.10, my wamp server is running just fine. But when I switch to older version of PHP (5.2.9) my wamp server tray icon is showing orange icon. If you click on Put Online I am getting following error.

I tried to change the port in httpd.conf to 8855 and still I am getting same error. How can I resolve this error?

> Could not execute menu item (internal error)[Exception] Could not perform service action:The service has not been started

[image: wamp]

[image: Aestan Tray Menu]

Comment: Skype was problem for me, I signed out from Skype and it worked for me.

Comment: If Skype is causing the problem, you can configure it to not use port 80. In Options->Advanced->Connection uncheck "Use port 80 and 443..." and restart Skype.

Answer (score 77):

By default , the WAMP server will take `80` as its working port.

You can change that port number as you like ... here are the steps to do that:

- click on WAMP server tray icon
- click on **apache**
- select **http.conf**

Here notepad will open ...

- scroll down and you will see the port number that WAMP server takes ...
- change that port number to:

  ```
  #Listen x.x.x.x:8080
  Listen 8080
  ```
- save that file and restart the services... it will work fine...
- now check by typing `http://localhost:8080/`.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using **Windows** try out the following:

1. Press (Windows+R)
2. enter "services.msc" and click "OK"
3. locate service with name 'wampapache'

and check if it's status is 'Running'. In case not, right click >> start.

Hope this helps!

---

If you have removed WAMP from boot services, it won't work – try the following:

- Press (Windows+R)
- enter "services.msc" and click "OK"
- locate service with name 'wampapache'
- Right click `wampapache` and `wampmysqld`, Click 'properties'
- and change Start Type to `Manual` or `automatic`

This will work!

Answer (score 6):

First go to Wamp->Apache->Service->Test Port 80

If its being user by Microsoft HTTPAPI / 2.0

Then the solution is to manually stop the service named **web deployment agent service**

If you have Microsoft Sql Server installed, even though the IIS service is disabled, it keeps a web service named httpapi2.0 running.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe an old version of the service was not uninstalled from windows

1. uninstall the old version running this command line

   > sc delete wampapache
2. Reinstall the service from wamp:

   Wamp Tray Icon -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service

It works for me, enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

1. Like you installed older version of PHP do the same with Apache. I picked version 2.0.63 and then I was able to run WAMP Server with PHP 5.2.9 with no problems.
2. I also read that it's problem with 64-bit version of WAMP.

Comment: It takes a little longer to start/restart server now though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the MySQL56 service was running and it has occupied the port of WAMP MySQL.After MySQL56 service stopped the WAMP server started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is reading this -> don't use php 5.3 anymore, switch to newer versions of php, because php 5.3 is using deprecated functions.

The following is a list of deprecated INI directives. Use of any of these INI directives will cause an E_DEPRECATED error to be thrown at startup, so I advise you to use newer version to develop.

```
define_syslog_variables
register_globals
register_long_arrays
safe_mode
magic_quotes_gpc
magic_quotes_runtime
magic_quotes_sybase
Comments starting with '#' are now deprecated in .INI files.
```

Deprecated functions:

```
call_user_method() (use call_user_func() instead)
call_user_method_array() (use call_user_func_array() instead)
define_syslog_variables()
dl()
ereg() (use preg_match() instead)
ereg_replace() (use preg_replace() instead)
eregi() (use preg_match() with the 'i' modifier instead)
eregi_replace() (use preg_replace() with the 'i' modifier instead)
set_magic_quotes_runtime() and its alias, magic_quotes_runtime()
session_register() (use the $_SESSION superglobal instead)
session_unregister() (use the $_SESSION superglobal instead)
session_is_registered() (use the $_SESSION superglobal instead)
set_socket_blocking() (use stream_set_blocking() instead)
split() (use preg_split() instead)
spliti() (use preg_split() with the 'i' modifier instead)
sql_regcase()
mysql_db_query() (use mysql_select_db() and mysql_query() instead)
mysql_escape_string() (use mysql_real_escape_string() instead)
Passing locale category names as strings is now deprecated. Use the LC_* family of constants instead.
The is_dst parameter to mktime(). Use the new timezone handling functions instead.
```

Deprecated features:

```
Assigning the return value of new by reference is now deprecated.
Call-time pass-by-reference is now deprecated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some applications like skype uses wamp's default port:80 so you have to find out which application is accessing this port you can easily find it by using [TCP View](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx). End the service accessing this port and restart wamp server. Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

- Open **`Task Manager`**
- Go to **Details**
- Find and kill `Skype...` apps

Restart `WampServer` and it should work