# WAMP Server getting an error "Could not execute menu item (internal error)"

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I downloaded WAMP server with version 2.2 and installed on a Windows 7 64-bit machine .

But the issue is it throws an error with following details:

---

**`Aestan Tray Menu`**

```
Could not execute menu item (internal error)
[Exception] Could not perform service action:
The service has not been started
```

---

Could anyone tell me what exactly it means and the solution if it is known?

Comment: Remove the "Use ports 80 and 443 as an alternate port" setting from Skype in Advanced Settings ;-)

Comment: this link has a solution for this problem.. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266656/could-not-execute-menu-item-internal-errorexception-when-changing-php-vers`

Comment: sorry i just saw that comment.

Comment: This problem occurs due to skype go to Skype  Options->Advanced->Connection uncheck "Use port 80 and 443..." and restart skype and the n Restart WAMP

Comment: Yes. It's Working for me too. First I started skype then start wamp server. This error appear.Once I quit skype and then i get the wamp Run process.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Left click on the tray of the WAMP icon, choose restart all services.

else

2. Choose stop service at all of the service, and start all again..
3. Restart your computer and rerun again.

If not, check if any of your configuration got wrong.

---

OR

Go to Wampsever->Apache->httpd.conf
and just change the line

Listen 0.0.0.0:80 Listen [::0]:80 as Listen 0.0.0.0:8080 Listen [::0]:8080

*copy the line find & replace..

here is the solution in youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nct5BBn6hW8

Comment: correct configuration went wrong somewhere but not able to figure out.. My observation is that, there may be a conflict with ports.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266656/could-not-execute-menu-item-internal-errorexception-when-changing-php-vers). Maybe it was same problem with you.

Comment: Yes, exactly after changing port it started properly.. :-)

Comment: how do you change port? port of what exactly?

Comment: Please see the Link on the comment above.

Comment: Yes, this answer worked for me.

Comment: gracias this worked for me