# Error on wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with Wamp server `(php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24`). When I start the Server, it refuses to go online. It brings this

> Error "Could Not execute menu ITEM (Internal Error)"

Any Assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you have Skype running at the same time ?? Otherwise , i think you have to check integrity of confs , try another version of httpd (2.2.9)

Comment: I have stopped Skype on the PC buut all in Vein

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not execute menu item (internal error)\[Exception\] - When changing PHP version from 5.3.1 to 5.2.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266656/could-not-execute-menu-item-internal-errorexception-when-changing-php-vers)

Answer (score 1):

1/c++2008 x86 redis is needed 
2/Go check the Wamp Project on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/wampserver2.2e/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266656/could-not-execute-menu-item-internal-errorexception-when-changing-php-vers 
your answer is here too