# Wampserver Green and Online (Could not execute menu item)

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I recently installed wampserver on this windows 10, there was no problem during the installation and the wamp icon is Green but when I tried to open Phpmyadmin on the tray it says "could not execute menu item (internal error) [exception] could not execute run action: the system cannot find the file specified" .

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266656/could-not-execute-menu-item-internal-errorexception-when-changing-php-vers

Comment: Did you install all the MSVC Runtime libraries that might be required to run Apache. See the section called [--- Visual C++ Packages ---](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) on the WAMPServer forum

Comment: @GrzegorzB. Thanks bro, I was able to solve the problem with wampserver on windows 10 by installing Visual C++ Packages 2012, 2013 and 2015. Then replacing wamp32 with wamp64.